# Android SDK installation issue

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to install Android SDK on eclipse. but I got into trouble about Android SDK Manager

when I executed Android Manager after downloading Eclipse ADT with the andoid SDK for window at [a link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

I could see only few pakages which aleady installed. I need more package to develop android project

if you guyz have any idea . please give some advise or solution

[image: below is picture of Android Manager. it should show more package including not installed package]

below is picture of Android Manager. it should show more package including not installed package

Answer (score 0):

I could guess you are behind the firewall or something. If your internet connection is up and behind the firewall, under
**tools>options>proxy settings** fill the details

optionally, you can **Force https://** in **others** tab.